# Where does Android compute the GPS location?

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm actually working on Android GPS and I was wondering which part of the code is responsible for computing the location based on satellites data ? My goal is to test some computing modification.

I know there is a daemon, gpsd, doing stuff but I can't find where is the transformation from azimuth & elevation to latitude & longitude and there is no method from the API level to override.

Can someone help me ?

Regards

Comment: if you the ans please upvote it

Comment: Not enough reputation x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**its service given by the android framework and locating mobile position is done by hardware  residing in mobile which gives locations to that service (Location service) and intern you receive it. So there is no method overiding**

I'm actually working on Android GPS and I was wondering which part of the code is responsible for computing the location based on satellites data ?

ans : service  (Location service) does it for you.